# How to move text to the right?

Tags: pdftex

How can I have the `AddToShipoutPictureFG` moved to the right? If possible with some margin

Inferring from `AtPageUpperLeft` to `AtPageUpperRight` doesn't work.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}% used for example-image
\usepackage{eso-pic}% used for header text http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

\title{My Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*
    {\AtPageUpperLeft
      {\parbox[t]
               {\paperwidth}
               {\mbox{}\\
                 Upper right line\\
                 other line
               }
      }
    }

\begin{figure}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not completely clear. Do you want to set the text right aligned? Then just use `\raggedright` before `\mbox{}`. Do you want to move something *a little bit* to the right? Then just use `\put(…,0){…}`. Du you want so place the text ragged left but right aligned at whole? Then use `\raggedright` and a `tabular` inside `\parbox`.

Answer (score 2):

You can move with the `\put` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}% used for example-image
\usepackage{eso-pic}% used for header text http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

\title{My Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*
    {\AtPageUpperLeft
      {\put(0.8\paperwidth,-1cm)
         {\parbox[t]
               {\paperwidth}
               {Upper right line\\
                other line
               }}
      }
    }

\begin{figure}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

But with a current LaTeX you can also use the shipout hooks directly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\title{My Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}
    {
      \put(0.8\paperwidth,-1cm){more on the right}    
    }

\begin{figure}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. `more on the right\\other line` in the second example does not work

Comment: use a \parbox inside, or a tabular, or use two \put command, or ...